# Have 3 columns with 4 li

Tags: html, css

I have an unordered list (ul), and I'm trying to make 3 columns. When I have 4 `li's` it only shows 2 columns. How can I make it have 3 columns with 4 `li's`?

Also, I want the `li` to go from left to right, not up to down, like this:

How it is:

1     3     5

2     4

I want it like this:

1     2     3

4     5

How can I make it show 3 columns when I have 4 `li`? And how can I make it show left to right?

Here is what I have so far:

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li>first</li>
    <li>second</li>
    <li>third</li>
    <li>fourth</li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
ul {
    background-color:yellow;
    -webkit-columns:3;
    -moz-columns:3;
    columns:3;
}
```

Here's the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bun4g2d0/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by floating block level elements and setting a width of `100%/3` on them, thereby creating three column layout. The browser will render the first three elements in row 1, the next three in row 2, the next three in row 3, etc...

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li>first</li>
    <li>second</li>
    <li>third</li>
    <li>fourth</li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
ul 
{
    background-color:yellow;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0; padding: 0;
}

ul li 
{
    background: red;
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
    width: calc(100%/3);
    margin: 0; padding: 0;
}
```

**Fiddle**

[https://jsfiddle.net/wfnkLd6m/4/](http://[1]:%20https://jsfiddle.net/bun4g2d0/2/)

Comment: You've just copy-pasted my answer. And why is there a need to use float:left with display:inline-block?

Comment: @Sidsec9 It's a bit conceited to think that I would copy and paste three lines of CSS in order to demonstrate a simple 3 column layout. There are clear differences as you've already noticed -- in this case I included `display:inline-block;` which is probably something I do out of bad habit at this point.

Answer (score 1):

```css
li {
    width: calc(100%/3);
    float: left;
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>first</li>
    <li>second</li>
    <li>third</li>
    <li>fourth</li>
</ul>
```

Something like [**this**](https://jsfiddle.net/bun4g2d0/2/)?